# Linq group by query with count and other fields in mvc4

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing linq query to get some details from table. I want to get count of `docStatus` with `"notVerified"` for each `clientID`.

My table structure is as follows

```
ID     clientId  clientName     empID       docStatus
1       IN1001    Infy           100        Verified
2       IN1001    Infy           101        notVerified
3       IN1001    Infy           102        notVerified
```

After querying I want data in the below form

```
clientID    clientName    Count
IN1001      Infy          2
```

This is what i tried below. I am able to get count but where i should put where condition in my below query.

```
var noofRecords = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc
                   group c by c.upld_docid into grouping
                   select new
                   {
                       key = grouping.Key,
                       Count = grouping.Count()
                   });
return noofRecords.Count();
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `upld_docid` ? Your query doesn't match the provided table which makes it confusing..

Comment: ID is upld_docid in the above table. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll what to place the `where` clause before the grouping (why to group these items that you are filtering out). Then, if you want the output as you specified, the easiest will be to group both by the `clientID` and `clientName`.

Also in your above query you are grouping by the `upld_docid` (`ID`) field - which is a unique field in your data - meaning all your groups have a size of 1 - as if you didn't group.

See below query, should do what you want:

```
var noofRecords = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc
                   where c.docStatus == "notVerified"
                   group c by new { c.clientID, c.clientName }  into grouping
                   select new
                   {
                        ClientId = grouping.Key.clientID,
                        ClientName = grouping.Key.clientName,
                        Count = grouping.Count()
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine for me. i should send noofRecords  from datalayer to controller as below right public list<records> getdetails{ above query and return noofRecords} if i am not wrong?

Comment: I'd not do it in a getter but that is a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the where in multiple places, one option:

```
var noofRecords = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc
                   where c.docStatus == "notVerified"
                   group c by c.upld_docid into grouping
                   select new
                   {
                        key = grouping.Key,
                        Count = grouping.Count()
                   });

return noofRecords.Count();
```

Be Aware !! You're returning the number of the records, and not the Property Count the you set to `grouping.Count()`

To get the expected results, you should do the following:

```
var noofRecords = (from c in db.ts_upld_doc
                   where c.docStatus == "notVerified"
                   group c by new { c.clientId , c.clientName } into grouping
                   select new
                   {
                      ClientId  = grouping.Key.clientId,
                      ClientName = grouping.Key.clientName,
                      Count = grouping.Count()
                   });

return noofRecords.ToList();
```

Comment: Query is working fine but the approach noofRecords.Count();  is not correct. I added one more row to db and i got result as below  [0] {key=IN1001,count=2}. [1] {key=IN1001,count=1}

Comment: Now i want result as clientID    clientName  Count   for each clientid

Comment: @NIRANJANG That is exactly what I said in the Be Aware section. I just answered the question of where should i put the `where` clause. Check the edited answer.